# {{myArray}} array binding not updating in view

Tags: typescript, angular

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder, ControlGroup, AbstractControl, Validators, Control} from "angular2/common";

@Component({
    selector: 'parameters-form',
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES,CORE_DIRECTIVES],
    template: `
      <h1>Parameters Form</h1>
      <p [(ngModel)]='arr'>{{ arr }}</p>
      <form [ngFormModel]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)"    class="ui form">

<div class="field">
            <label for="systemParameters">System Parameters</label>
            <input type="number"
                   id="systemParameters"
                   placeholder="systemParameters Param"
                   [ngFormControl]="systemParameters">

            <button type="button" (click)="addToArray(systemParameters.value)">Add</button>

          </div>
<button type="submit" class="ui button">Submit</button>
      </form>
    `
})

export class ParametersForm {
  myForm: ControlGroup;
  systemParameters: AbstractControl;
  arr: number[];
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = fb.group({
      "realisations" : [""],
      "numConstSteps" : [""],
      "timeHorizon": [""],
      "continuationStep" : [""],
      "continuationStepSign" : [""],
      "numberOfModelParameters" : [""],
      "systemParameters" : [],
      "param" : [""],
      "netLogoFile" : [""],
      "numberOfModelVariables" : [""],
      "restrictOperator" : [""],
      "liftOperator" : [""],
      "xInitial" : [""]

    });
    this.arr = [];
    this.systemParameters = this.myForm.controls["systemParameters"];
  }
  addToArray(value: any): void {
    this.arr.push(value);
    (<Control>this.systemParameters).updateValue("");
  }
  onSubmit(form: any): void {
    console.log(this.arr);
    form.systemParameters = this.arr;
    console.log("your submitted value:", form)
  }

}
```

i am trying to show the values inside Arr (array) in real-time, when user inputs value in systemParameters field by invoking the Add function which pushes the value to `arr` array.

this is the error `No value accessor for ''" in [arr in ParametersForm@2:9]`

its cause from the `ngModel` thats as much as i know.

**Updated:** based on  Günter's comments I removed both `ngModel` and Core directives. The `{{arr}}` contents do not show but internally in the class they do.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add `CORE_DIRECTIVES` anymore. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496514/ngmodel-no-value-accessor-for for a similar question. Can you provide a plunker?

Comment: You can't use `ngModel` like that on a `p` element. `ngModel` is for input elements.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer ah here is a plunker `http://plnkr.co/edit/dHJf8QEhhvU5LupdDcmX?p=preview` so what can i do to show the array values in real time?

Comment: Thanks. Still, what's the point of adding `[(ngModel)]` on a `<p` element?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i am just tring to figure out how to show the values of the array as said and the only thing i saw that can mimick this functionality is ngModel i guess - i am new at angularjs 2 really so you could say i am fiddling about while having a specific project in mind..

Comment: Just remove the `[(ngModel)]` there. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: Removed both ngModel and Core directives now. tried it without ngModel as well. the arr content do not show but internally in the class they do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** 
As of beta.16, `{{myArray}}` will now update in the view, even if the array reference hasn't changed.  See also [{{myArray}} now updates in the view as of beta.16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37301141/myarray-now-updates-in-the-view-as-of-beta-16)

---

**Original answer:**

Angular change detection compares by value, and for arrays and objects, that means the array or object reference.  If your view simply has `{{arr}` in it, then that binding in the view won't update when you `push()` items onto the array, because the array reference hasn't changed.

However, normally, a template will loop over the items in an array:

```
<div *ngFor="item of arr">{{item}}</div>
```

In this case, Angular change detection will have a binding for each item of the array, so `push()` updates will be noticed, and the view will be updated.

For debugging, if you instead use `{{arr | json}}`, you'll also see the view update when you `push()` onto the array.  (This is because the JsonPipe is stateful, which causes Angular change detection to evaluate it every change detection cycle.)

Comment: thanks for your input this seems like the best practice so i marked this as the correct answer for future reference. One question though, why is `{{arr | json}}` only for debugging?

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou, because normally you don't want to show a string version of an array or object to your users.

Answer (score 1):

Angular change detection doesn't recognize changes within arrays, only changes to the array reference

```
  addToArray(value: any): void {
    // Angular doesn't recognize this
    this.arr.push(value);
    (<Control>this.systemParameters).updateValue("");
  }
```

as workaround you can use

```
  addToArray(value: any): void {
    this.arr.push(value);
    this.arr = this.arr.slice();
    (<Control>this.systemParameters).updateValue("");
  }
```

to create a copy of the array. Angular recognizes this because the array itself is another one.

Checking for a better way ...

Comment: hmm updated plunker with this, but it says [object, mousevent] ?

Comment: ah nvm i had this `addToArray($event, systemParameters.value)` in my local code after i fiddled some more with the code which is not present here in stackoverflow post, removed it and now shows values, thank you!

Comment: I agree with what you said, but I think you may confuse people by saying that "Angular change detection doesn't recognize changes within arrays", because normally there is an `NgFor` associated with the array in the template, and change detection will then recognize changes to the items.  See my answer for more details.

Comment: @MarkRajcok thanks for the feedback. I remember you mentioning it recently.