# Angular2/PrimeNG - Cant display Dropdown

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm using PrimeNG & Angular2 for my app.

I've got a component which should show a dropdown menu of selectable themes.
I've followed the [PrimeNG Dropdown](http://primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown) documentation and as far as I can see I've got everything build up the same way. But I'm always getting the Error "No value accessor for '' "

theme.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core'
import { Dropdown, SelectItem} from 'primeng/primeng';

@Component({
   selector: 'my-themes',
   templateUrl: 'dist/html/theme.component.html',
   directives: [Dropdown],
})


export class ThemeComponent {
   selectables: SelectItem[];
   style: string;

   constructor() {
      this.selectables = [];
      this.selectables.push({ label: 'Nightflat', value: 'Nightflat' });
      this.selectables.push({ label: 'Flat', value: 'Flat' });
   }
   ngOnInit() {

   }

}
```

theme.component.html:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="selectables" [(ngModel)]="style"></p-dropdown>
```

Any ideas where the problem might be? :( 
Edit: The problem actuallyy is ngModel. The Dropdown gets displayed if I remove it from the html tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many similar issues are there have a look here

- https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/549
- [ngModel: No value accessor for ''](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34496514/5043867)

also you can avoid your error message by just changing your `ngModel` with `model` but there is current issue with primeng which is being processed.

also try  using depracted forms disable.

```
import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms } from '@angular/forms';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
disableDeprecatedForms(),
provideForms()]);
```

## update

according to officials of primeng problem has been resolved see here.

- http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=46238

Answer (score 0):

There are many similar issues are there have a look here

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/549
ngModel: No value accessor for ''

I have gotten the same console error ,
just add [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true} is ok